# Memory consumption java file stream

Tags: java, memory, lambda, java-8

I'm reading a file through a java nio interface, directly to a stream. This launches async http requests and handles these in the future. Every 10,000 records, I upload this result to a server and I clear the records, so this clears my memory consumption.
I start with the byte array, that stays in the memory constantly. The http client (`commons CloseableHttpAsyncClient`) fires the requests async, so these are fired all at once in the beginning.
Is there a way to limit the lambda stream in a way that I can limit the number of lines that are processed at the same time? Thus controlling my memory.

```
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(file)))
    .lines()
    .map(line -> CsvLine.create(line))
    .filter(line -> !line.isHeader())
    .forEach(line -> getResult(line, new FutureCallback<HttpResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void completed(HttpResponse response) {
            try {
                result.addLine(response);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOGGER.error("IOException, cannot write to server", e);
                todo.set(-1); // finish in error
            } finally {
                todo.decrementAndGet();
            }
       }

       @Override
       public void failed(Exception ex) {
           handleError();
       }

       @Override
       public void cancelled() {
           handleError();
       }
    }
));
```

Comment: Can't you just run the code in chunks of 10000? Loop through the stream and once you hit 10000 run all the calls.

Comment: Use a `for` loop. There is no reason to write it as a stream solution when only two of thirty lines are actual functional programming…

Comment: I'm handling 10 million rows, and want to go bigger in the future, using a for loop will cause them to go all in memory and consume all my memory

Comment: (off topic) can you `skip(1)` instead of doing the `isHeader` filter on every row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try using a Semaphore to throttle your stream so that only a certain maximum async requests are outstanding at a time.  It might look like this:

```
Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(MAX_CONCURRENT_REQUESTS, true); // false if FIFO is not important
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(file)))
.lines()
        .map(line -> CsvLine.create(line))
        .filter(line -> !line.isHeader())
        .forEach(line -> {
            try {
                if (!semaphore.tryAcquire(ASYNC_REQUEST_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
                    handleTimeout();
                } else {
                    getResult(line, new FutureCallback<HttpResponse>() {
                        @Override
                        public void completed(HttpResponse response) {
                            try {
                                result.addLine(response);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                LOGGER.error("IOException, cannot write to server", e);
                                todo.set(-1); // finish in error
                            } finally {
                                todo.decrementAndGet();
                                semaphore.release();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void failed(Exception ex) {
                            handleError();
                            semaphore.release();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void cancelled() {
                            handleError();
                            semaphore.release();
                        }
                    }
                    );
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // handle appropriately
            }

        });
```

Comment: I now solved it like this a bit, I will refactor my code accordingly. thanks